# Extract images from several doc files

Tags: 14.04, files

I have a folder with several doc files which contain a few images each of them. I want to extract those images from the docs:

```
unzip foo.docx "word/media/*"
```

The above command can extract the images from one file, but how can I apply this command to every file in a folder without typing one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple loop will do the trick. `unzip` supports specifying a target directory, so you can do

```
for f in *.docx
do
    mkdir -p "$f"-images
    unzip "$f" "word/media/*" -d "$f"-images
done
```

Comment: I have a problem with this. Docs has the same name on images. Is there any way to change the name of the exported images to a simple 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. I don't mind to keep which image is from which file

Comment: @AnastasiosVentouris it's easier to separate out which image is from which file. See update.

Answer (score 0):

Use find command:

```
find . -type f -name "*.docx" -execdir unzip {} "word/media/*" \;
```

Comment: This exract everything from the file and not only the images